# Only accept Azure Mobile Apps connections from Verified Applications?

Tags: authentication, azure-mobile-services

I have a mobile application which relies on a Windows Azure App Services Back-end. I want to tie down some security vulnerabilities. For example, someone can currently access all my records, modify or delete them. Not Ideal...

I only want users to be able to access their own records (data privacy) and I want to ensure that only my application can POST data to the server, i.e. an unofficial potentially corrupted app shouldn't be able to POST data and corrupt my database. Maybe some sort of TLS etc. approach might do this? This restriction (if possible) would likely allow me to implement the access-to-own-records-only logic in the mobile app rather than backend?

How could I ensure only legitimate versions of my app can interact with my back-end?

Answer (score 2):

Azure Mobile Apps (an SDK on top of a standard Node/Express or ASP.NET app that can be deployed to Azure App Service) provides a mechanism that your web or mobile app can access records in a SQL database.   The users ID is stored alongside the record on a POST and the users ID is also used as part of the query when returning records.

See https://shellmonger.com/30-days-of-azure-mobile-apps-the-table-of-contents/ - particularly Day 6 (for Node/Express) and 18 (for ASP.NET)

As to your last question - how to ensure only legit versions of the app can interact with your backend - you can't.  Trivially, you might think to use a shared secret that needs to be passed IN ADDITION TO other authentication requirements.  However, this does not stop someone sniffing the wire and using the same shared secret.  There is virtually no way that you can stop a determined player from accessing your backend without using an approved app.

Comment: Would the shared secret not be protected by only interacting with the backend using TLS/SSL?

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards It can still be brute-forced. A determined user can run a simple script to hit your REST API until they get a 200. SSL merely makes determination of the secret inconvenient.

Comment: It's trivial.  Configure Fiddler to intercept SSL traffic - run your app - see the headers and replicate them.  Do not rely on a shared secret - once the shared secret is in the wild, your secret is no longer secret.

Comment: OK, what about if the server accepts all pieces of info, but only records the ones with the correct secret? That way externally, you have no way of knowing if it has worked or not, making brute-forcing impossible? I suppose that still leaves a DoS attach (albeit slightly mitigated), but it does protect the database from corruption?